# Android Edittext can't be focused on API 22 (code works fine on API 23 and higher)

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I have an application, it takes info from EditText and after pressing the Button uses the String from it.
My  application works good on api23 and higher but on api22 EditText couldn't be focused. 
I can't understand what happends.

I use android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:focusable="true", 
try to use EditText.setSelected(true), EditText.setFocusable(true);
but there is no any result.
Application use style "AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

XML-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgr"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textForParsing"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/hintInRequest"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        />

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonForParsing"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="@string/Find"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textForParsing" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    String textFromEdit;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = findViewById(R.id.textForParsing);
        editText.setSelected(true);
        editText.setFocusable(true);

        button = findViewById(R.id.buttonForParsing);

        View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            textFromEdit = editText.getText().toString(); 
};
            button.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
```

Comment: are you mean you can't write and show keybord into EditText on below API 22 ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja yes, the keyboard isn't showed on API 22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Edittext in API 22 has problems with such attribute as android:textIsSelectable="true". The app works wonderful without it.